# Side-By-Side Configuration and Wix Installer

Tags: visual-c++, wix, wix3.5, visual-c++-2008

I'm working on WiX installer for a C++ VC9 x64 application which is dependent on Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2092)

To achieve this I added following merge modules in my WiX package.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
    <Merge Id="VCRedist" SourceFile="X\Wix\Microsoft_VC90_CRT_x86_x64.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
    <Merge Id="VCRedistAlt" SourceFile="X\Wix\Microsoft_VC90_ATL_x86_x64.msm" DiskId="1" Language="0"/>
</DirectoryRef>
<Feature Id="VCRedist" Title="Visual C++ 9.0 x64 Runtime" AllowAdvertise="no" Display="hidden" Level="1">
    <MergeRef Id="VCRedist"/>
    <MergeRef Id="VCRedistAlt"/>
</Feature>
```

Result this in log file; I presume here that it is getting installed correctly.

```
MSI (s) (18:20) [17:16:56:698]: Executing op: AssemblyPublish(Feature=VCRedist,Component={22D75DAD-658C-3109-91F7-4CB1A0729109},AssemblyType=2,,AssemblyName=Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.6161",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32",)
MsiPublishAssemblies: Application Context:Global, Assembly Name:Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.6161",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"
MSI (s) (18:20) [17:16:56:698]: Executing op: AssemblyPublish(Feature=VCRedist,Component={74C57B6B-FF6E-3825-BED2-78E14E3E0E3C},AssemblyType=2,,AssemblyName=Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version="9.0.30729.6161",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32",)
MsiPublishAssemblies: Application Context:Global, Assembly Name:Microsoft.VC90.ATL,version="9.0.30729.6161",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",processorArchitecture="amd64",type="win32"
```

The application doesn't run on my clean Win7 x64 system and throw Side-by-Side configuration error.

Although if I install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) from microsoft website application run. I understand I'm missing something but not sure how to solve this.